# maven archtype called from archetype?

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

Folks, does anyone know if it is possible to call an archetype project from INSIDE the running of another archetype?

I'd like to have an archetype that creates a project, as normal.  However, if a particular variable is set, I'd like this to trigger a call to run another archtype to create an ADDITIONAL project based on THAT archetype.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to create a plugin based on archetype:generate, then you would use that  plugin to generate an archetype, for example `user1959175:generate -DgroupId=...`